# HttpUrlConnection either 'unauthorized' or 'already connected'

Tags: java, exception, httpurlconnection

I've got a problem with `HttpUrlConnection`.

I want to download a file from internet.
The first time it works perfectly.
But when I try again, I have an exception I'm "already connected", or "connect in progress".

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: connect in 
progress
```

I googled and found I need to remove some things like `con.setDoOutput(true);`.
I did it and reboot my program.
Now I've got another exception: `401 unauthorized`.

I don't see what to do.
my code:

```
public boolean creerSession(String endpoint) throws IOException, JSONException, InterruptedException {
    // Ouverture de la connexion
    String url = new StringBuilder(endpoint).append("/auth").toString();
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    validerAll();
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Définition des Request header
    String urlParameters = new StringBuilder("username=").append(this.login).append("&password=").append(this.password).toString();        
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.getRequestMethod();

    // Envoi de la requete en POST
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you use `disconnect()` once you're done with the `HttpURLConnection con` object? Then, you have to create a new instance by calling again `(HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection()` at each request

Comment: Stack trace please, of both exceptions, in your question.

Comment: "401 unauthorized" I would imagine is the response you got from the web service, indicating that your request was not authorized. Issue is very likely in how you are trying to get authorized such as Wrong/missing user/password combination

Answer (score 0):

@Emanuele Giona You're right, disconnect() was missing, but even if I try with that, the error follows.
@Quitium That's what I explained: if I uncomment my code

```
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.getRequestMethod();
con.setDoOutput(true);
```

I have an unauthorized Exception

Stack trace (first time it's ok, a few minutes later, the problem with connect in progress comes back...)

`Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61323', transport: 'socket'
ticket de la session : XIZZAxWt36k0+lrEiVDKO6ijKitlwdwL1kx1EG1tiGGV3fJ3gw/In9zkBhTRjuTVWupmAh3xPQ1jRkByj50uRl0sn1vDdzE+gRiNHFIiF4TOmBQXwSkIPA==
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: connect in progress
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:517)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:374)
    at GedWSTesting.downloadFile(GedWSTesting.java:60)
    at GedWSTesting.main(GedWSTesting.java:32)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61323', transport: 'socket'`

Process finished with exit code 1

my code (lines 57 → 64)

```
// open the connection
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) downloadUrl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "LLCookie=" + mainSession.getTicket() + "; path=/livelink/; secure");
    con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    con.setReadTimeout(50000);
    con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    con.connect();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to answer so late. The problem was disconnect().